Save an image to a MySQL database using Python and a jpeg URL I already know
I want to add a lot of images to MySQL as BLOB entries without downloading them locally first. I already have the URLs for all of the JPEG images.
It seems redundant to download locally then upload them to MySQL server.

For this you need to run your code on the MySQL server, which is what stored procedures do.
